# php: gzdecode() insufficient memory

Tags: php, curl

Sometimes when downloading sources of a webpage and trying to decode it, i get an error: gzdecode() insufficient memory. (memory limit i 500m, usage far below that)

I include headers with my curl output, those are separated from the content correctly, before decoding. Content encoding header of the pages is clearly gzip. I read on php.net that including a length argument could cause such a crash, but I do not use length argument with gzdecode.

So while seemingly everything should be fine, I still get the error. Last time I found it with this page: https://ahmia.fi/address/.

Is there probably something with the https I do not know about? My curl settiing is \CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CURLOPT_ENCODING` The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and "gzip". If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent.

try this:

```
CURLOPT_ENCODING => ""
```

Comment: Suppose it does not mean curl will automatically decode it for me, does it?

Comment: No it doesn't, just informs the other server about the supported encoding types it handles.