# gzdecode() insufficient memory - size is exhausted

Tags: php, out-of-memory, gzip, zlib

Do you know any solucion to unpack large .gz in php (>200 MB .gz, >4GB original... maybe in packs of >1GB or >2GB inside) ?

Solucion of decode .gz part by part is needed.

Code
`gzdecode(@file_get_contents($file))`

gets PHP error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate ...

of course.

I cannot increase the PHP memory limit of the webserver, and it seems to be no point in trying while data >>1GB.

Using inflate_add() isn't solution, it generates the same "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size ... exhausted ...".

Any idea?
(I found no answers in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346756/php-gzdecode-insufficient-memory), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861382/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-is-exhausted-with-wordpress-plugin-wp-typography) etc.)

Comment: You’ll want to look into https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gzopen()` instead of `gzdcode()`. Then you can read small chunks at a time with `gzread()`.

Answer (score 0):

came right here, my error might be different, but Google showed this page first. so for anyone coming here:

'gzdecode(): insufficient memory'

In my case this was due to a wrongly placed boolean that told gzdecode the length of decoding would be 1.